# Ticketee Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anyone who did the "Ticketee" app from book "Rails 4 in Action".
I have a question.
After making the title for the page, the RSpec shows me an error and in book, it is written that there should be no errors.

The title should contain "Project Name - Projects - Ticketee" and in my app, it only contains "Ticketee" and I don't know why.

Here is link to my Github
[Ticketee](https://github.com/fazowski/Ticketee)

Comment: Add minimal, relevant samples from your code into your question.

Comment: Hi fafal - I'm one of the authors of Rails 4 in Action and can help you fix your problem, if you can provide a specific error with the related code. You can also compare your code with our code repository here - https://github.com/rubysherpas/r4ia_examples

Comment: The next time you post a question, please post **code snippets** so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because in your application.html.erb, you have two `title` tags.

https://github.com/fazowski/Ticketee/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L4

Remove the `title` element from line 4.

Now run

```
bundle exec rspec
```

This time the tests should pass.